# Serverless function does not work when invoked remotely in python lambda function

Tags: python, serverless-framework

I am working on getting the lambda function detailed in the below article in my aws environment. My code all deploys but it does not get executed when I execute serverless invoke -f function_name. It gets stuck at Serverless: Invoke invoke.

Please help.
https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/

### serverless.yml

```
service: python-lambda6

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  stage: dev
  region: ca-central-1

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux

functions:
  numpy:
    handler: handler.main
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: 'ANY {proxy+}'
```

### handler.py

```
import numpy as np
import json

def main(event, context):
    a = np.arange(15).reshape(3, 5);
    print("Your numpy array:")
    print(a)

    body = {
        "message": "Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!",
        "input": event
    }

    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps(body)
    }

    return response


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main('', '')
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "python-lambda6",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "handler.py",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "serverless-python-requirements": "^5.1.0"
  }
}
```

### Output of sls deploy

```
$ serverless deploy
Serverless: Load command interactiveCli
Serverless: Load command config
Serverless: Load command config:credentials
Serverless: Load command create
Serverless: Load command install
Serverless: Load command package
Serverless: Load command deploy
Serverless: Load command deploy:function
Serverless: Load command deploy:list
Serverless: Load command deploy:list:functions
Serverless: Load command invoke
Serverless: Load command invoke:local
Serverless: Load command info
Serverless: Load command logs
Serverless: Load command metrics
Serverless: Load command print
Serverless: Load command remove
Serverless: Load command rollback
Serverless: Load command rollback:function
Serverless: Load command slstats
Serverless: Load command plugin
Serverless: Load command plugin
Serverless: Load command plugin:install
Serverless: Load command plugin
Serverless: Load command plugin:uninstall
Serverless: Load command plugin
Serverless: Load command plugin:list
Serverless: Load command plugin
Serverless: Load command plugin:search
Serverless: Load command config
Serverless: Load command config:credentials
Serverless: Load command rollback
Serverless: Load command rollback:function
Serverless: Load command upgrade
Serverless: Load command uninstall
Serverless: Load command requirements
Serverless: Load command requirements:clean
Serverless: Load command requirements:install
Serverless: Load command requirements:cleanCache
Serverless: Load command login
Serverless: Load command logout
Serverless: Load command generate-event
Serverless: Load command test
Serverless: Load command dashboard
Serverless: Load command output
Serverless: Load command output:get
Serverless: Load command output:list
Serverless: Load command param
Serverless: Load command param:get
Serverless: Load command param:list
Serverless: Invoke deploy
Serverless: Invoke package
Serverless: Invoke aws:common:validate
Serverless: Invoke aws:common:cleanupTempDir
Serverless: Generated requirements from C:\Kala Data\GIT files\python-lambda6\requirements.txt in C:\Kala Data\GIT files\python-lambda6\.serverless\requirements.txt...
Serverless: Using static cache of requirements found at C:\Users\Kala\AppData\Local\UnitedIncome\serverless-python-requirements\Cache\944d0e70712137ebd98ff5d2cd1a9109a0543a7ceef5dfa04bb88c6d7fd801d4_slspyc ...
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Injecting required Python packages to package...
Serverless: Invoke aws:package:finalize
Serverless: Invoke aws:common:moveArtifactsToPackage
Serverless: Invoke aws:common:validate
Serverless: Invoke aws:deploy:deploy
Serverless: [AWS cloudformation 400 0.175s 0 retries] describeStacks({ StackName: 'python-lambda6-dev' })
Serverless: Creating Stack...
Serverless: [AWS cloudformation 200 0.22s 0 retries] createStack({ StackName: 'python-lambda6-dev',
  OnFailure: 'DELETE',
  Capabilities: [ 'CAPABILITY_IAM', 'CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM', [length]: 2 ],
  Parameters: [ [length]: 0 ],
  TemplateBody:
   '{"AWSTemplateFormatVersion":"2010-09-09","Description":"The AWS CloudFormation template for this Serverless application","Resources":{"ServerlessDeploymentBucket":{"Type":"AWS::S3::Bucket","Properties":{"BucketEncryption":{"ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration":[{"ServerSideEncryptionByDefault":{"SSEAlgorithm":"AES256"}}]}}},"ServerlessDeploymentBucketPolicy":{"Type":"AWS::S3::BucketPolicy","Properties":{"Bucket":{"Ref":"ServerlessDeploymentBucket"},"PolicyDocument":{"Statement":[{"Action":"s3:*","Effect":"Deny","Principal":"*","Resource":[{"Fn::Join":["",["arn:",{"Ref":"AWS::Partition"},":s3:::",{"Ref":"ServerlessDeploymentBucket"},"/*"]]}],"Condition":{"Bool":{"aws:SecureTransport":false}}}]}}}},"Outputs":{"ServerlessDeploymentBucketName":{"Value":{"Ref":"ServerlessDeploymentBucket"}}}}',
  Tags: [ { Key: 'STAGE', Value: 'dev' }, [length]: 1 ] })
Serverless: Checking Stack create progress...
Serverless: [AWS cloudformation 200 0.106s 0 retries] describeStackEvents({ StackName:
   'arn:aws:cloudformation:ca-central-1:944837795657:stack/python-lambda6-dev/f684f390-5fe1-11ea-b064-02dcd16b7172' })
...Serverless: [AWS cloudformation 200 0.098s 0 retries] describeStackEvents({ StackName:
   'arn:aws:cloudformation:ca-central-1:944837795657:stack/python-lambda6-dev/f684f390-5fe1-11ea-b064-02dcd16b7172' })
Serverless: [AWS cloudformation 200 0.102s 0 retries] describeStackEvents({ StackName:
   'arn:aws:cloudformation:ca-central-1:944837795657:stack/python-lambda6-dev/f684f390-5fe1-11ea-b064-02dcd16b7172' })
Serverless: [AWS cloudformation 200 0.109s 0 retries] describeStackEvents({ StackName:
   'arn:aws:cloudformation:ca-central-1:944837795657:stack/python-lambda6-dev/f684f390-5fe1-11ea-b064-02dcd16b7172' })
Serverless: [AWS cloudformation 200 0.096s 0 retries] describeStackEvents({ StackName:
   'arn:aws:cloudformation:ca-central-1:944837795657:stack/python-lambda6-dev/f684f390-5fe1-11ea-b064-02dcd16b7172' })
.Serverless: [AWS cloudformation 200 0.1s 0 retries] describeStackEvents({ StackName:
   'arn:aws:cloudformation:ca-central-1:944837795657:stack/python-lambda6-dev/f684f390-5fe1-11ea-b064-02dcd16b7172' })
....
Serverless: Stack create finished...
Serverless: [AWS cloudformation 200 0.106s 0 retries] describeStackResource({ StackName: 'python-lambda6-dev',
  LogicalResourceId: 'ServerlessDeploymentBucket' })
Serverless: [AWS s3 200 0.141s 0 retries] listObjectsV2({ Bucket:
   'python-lambda6-dev-serverlessdeploymentbucket-1bqpkzk33k7zr',
  Prefix: 'serverless/python-lambda6/dev' })
Serverless: [AWS lambda 404 0.141s 0 retries] getFunction({ FunctionName: 'python-lambda6-dev-numpy' })
Serverless: [AWS sts 200 0.163s 0 retries] getCallerIdentity({})
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3...
Serverless: [AWS s3 200 0.13s 0 retries] putObject({ Body:
   <Buffer 7b 22 41 57 53 54 65 6d 70 6c 61 74 65 46 6f 72 6d 61 74 56 65 72 73 69 6f 6e 22 3a 22 32 30 31 30 2d 30 39 2d 30 39 22 2c 22 44 65 73 63 72 69 70 74 ... >,
  Bucket:
   'python-lambda6-dev-serverlessdeploymentbucket-1bqpkzk33k7zr',
  Key:
   'serverless/python-lambda6/dev/1583523468652-2020-03-06T19:37:48.652Z/compiled-cloudformation-template.json',
  ContentType: 'application/json',
  Metadata:
   { filesha256: 'PqQ1S0FgEvlax3wxW0kW7nb2BNBLEeAPNrhA0epE3zI=' } })
Serverless: Uploading artifacts...
Serverless: Uploading service python-lambda6.zip file to S3 (50.64 MB)...
Serverless: [AWS s3 200 0.158s 0 retries] createMultipartUpload({ Bucket:
   'python-lambda6-dev-serverlessdeploymentbucket-1bqpkzk33k7zr',
  Key:
   'serverless/python-lambda6/dev/1583523468652-2020-03-06T19:37:48.652Z/python-lambda6.zip',
  ContentType: 'application/zip',
  Metadata:
   { filesha256: '4qps0IOJOc0HgL2Ouk5LAtT0InTvGM1tZHgL1l/UDqc=' } })
Serverless: [AWS s3 200 0.906s 0 retries] uploadPart({ Body:
   <Buffer 50 4b 03 04 0a 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 21 00 00 b9 da f7 29 00 00 00 27 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 2e 69 64 65 61 2f 2e 67 69 74 69 67 6e 6f 72 65 53 56 70 49 ... >,
  ContentLength: 5242880,
  PartNumber: 1,
  Bucket:
   'python-lambda6-dev-serverlessdeploymentbucket-1bqpkzk33k7zr',
  Key:
   'serverless/python-lambda6/dev/1583523468652-2020-03-06T19:37:48.652Z/python-lambda6.zip',
  UploadId:
   'qrCiUGI6fspjB7cglWxDXc1vXULbLtkECg9WRdiiDkZsomPjC3BnrV3XfHlSpIbYJKQRpCeHzH8A8nRmK.PRdgSRrdykf74YHY.Sc6wRwRY5oQM4Vsp60Y0x.A.6JdJy' })
Serverless: [AWS s3 200 1.213s 0 retries] uploadPart({ Body:
   <Buffer 3e 7e 60 f9 c1 38 7e b3 ba de 89 e3 90 9e 9d 9f be c0 29 8d 12 a5 7a 27 16 a0 e8 d9 16 14 a8 23 fe ff da d5 5a 8a 42 9a f7 61 ce d1 9e cc e7 67 74 12 ... >,
  ContentLength: 5242880,
  PartNumber: 5,
  Bucket:
   'python-lambda6-dev-serverlessdeploymentbucket-1bqpkzk33k7zr',
  Key:
   'serverless/python-lambda6/dev/1583523468652-2020-03-06T19:37:48.652Z/python-lambda6.zip',
  UploadId:
   'qrCiUGI6fspjB7cglWxDXc1vXULbLtkECg9WRdiiDkZsomPjC3BnrV3XfHlSpIbYJKQRpCeHzH8A8nRmK.PRdgSRrdykf74YHY.Sc6wRwRY5oQM4Vsp60Y0x.A.6JdJy' })
Serverless: [AWS s3 200 3.531s 0 retries] uploadPart({ Body:
   <Buffer ba 0e 86 f6 32 62 84 af 1d 4c 4c 63 84 ba 0e 86 26 34 e6 11 ea 3a 98 7a 8d 11 a2 5a 8c a1 3b 9c 8d 6b 52 cb 75 12 a1 ae 4d 42 4c 83 c6 08 75 1d cc 0a ... >,
  ContentLength: 5242880,
  PartNumber: 2,
  Bucket:
   'python-lambda6-dev-serverlessdeploymentbucket-1bqpkzk33k7zr',
  Key:
   'serverless/python-lambda6/dev/1583523468652-2020-03-06T19:37:48.652Z/python-lambda6.zip',
  UploadId:
   'qrCiUGI6fspjB7cglWxDXc1vXULbLtkECg9WRdiiDkZsomPjC3BnrV3XfHlSpIbYJKQRpCeHzH8A8nRmK.PRdgSRrdykf74YHY.Sc6wRwRY5oQM4Vsp60Y0x.A.6JdJy' })
Serverless: [AWS s3 200 3.583s 0 retries] uploadPart({ Body:
   <Buffer 46 ab bc 39 db 2c ca 68 8e fb 5b ce e1 c8 f1 c4 29 16 a5 6c ee 5e fa 2b b1 28 63 9b bb bf 12 8b b2 14 98 6e 28 18 f8 3b f0 96 38 65 8e 9c 14 92 f6 ff ... >,
  ContentLength: 5242880,
  PartNumber: 3,
  Bucket:
   'python-lambda6-dev-serverlessdeploymentbucket-1bqpkzk33k7zr',
  Key:
   'serverless/python-lambda6/dev/1583523468652-2020-03-06T19:37:48.652Z/python-lambda6.zip',
  UploadId:
   'qrCiUGI6fspjB7cglWxDXc1vXULbLtkECg9WRdiiDkZsomPjC3BnrV3XfHlSpIbYJKQRpCeHzH8A8nRmK.PRdgSRrdykf74YHY.Sc6wRwRY5oQM4Vsp60Y0x.A.6JdJy' })
Serverless: [AWS s3 200 2.828s 0 retries] uploadPart({ Body:
   <Buffer 81 c7 0b fa 38 c6 d1 53 33 87 07 90 4b c8 8a f0 76 08 5d 0d 9b 42 d5 2c c7 27 43 1c f5 18 20 31 e6 62 08 07 0c 0c e7 aa 2e b0 3f bf 97 c5 f9 d5 94 dc ... >,
  ContentLength: 5242880,
  PartNumber: 4,
  Bucket:
   'python-lambda6-dev-serverlessdeploymentbucket-1bqpkzk33k7zr',
  Key:
   'serverless/python-lambda6/dev/1583523468652-2020-03-06T19:37:48.652Z/python-lambda6.zip',
  UploadId:
   'qrCiUGI6fspjB7cglWxDXc1vXULbLtkECg9WRdiiDkZsomPjC3BnrV3XfHlSpIbYJKQRpCeHzH8A8nRmK.PRdgSRrdykf74YHY.Sc6wRwRY5oQM4Vsp60Y0x.A.6JdJy' })
Serverless: [AWS s3 200 1.302s 0 retries] uploadPart({ Body:
   <Buffer 76 54 0a e0 16 03 c0 85 58 d9 9b ec c7 9a 95 1b fa fa 73 b2 17 c0 85 9e 46 db e2 dc e2 f7 6c 28 db 01 07 6b 4c f0 0f 70 42 63 8d fd 06 f8 08 5f 1c 20 ... >,
  ContentLength: 5242880,
  PartNumber: 9,
  Bucket:
   'python-lambda6-dev-serverlessdeploymentbucket-1bqpkzk33k7zr',
  Key:
   'serverless/python-lambda6/dev/1583523468652-2020-03-06T19:37:48.652Z/python-lambda6.zip',
  UploadId:
   'qrCiUGI6fspjB7cglWxDXc1vXULbLtkECg9WRdiiDkZsomPjC3BnrV3XfHlSpIbYJKQRpCeHzH8A8nRmK.PRdgSRrdykf74YHY.Sc6wRwRY5oQM4Vsp60Y0x.A.6JdJy' })
Serverless: [AWS s3 200 1.689s 0 retries] uploadPart({ Body:
   <Buffer 2b 2e cf 29 78 84 fe 9a aa 1f 7e 83 6b 19 2a da 08 4d 4c d9 ec 61 f5 b0 0a 5a f8 37 c6 9f 66 d0 9a d6 52 03 f3 61 78 3b f5 ea 45 f1 7a 60 8c 91 d4 5f ... >,
  ContentLength: 5242880,
  PartNumber: 7,
  Bucket:
   'python-lambda6-dev-serverlessdeploymentbucket-1bqpkzk33k7zr',
  Key:
   'serverless/python-lambda6/dev/1583523468652-2020-03-06T19:37:48.652Z/python-lambda6.zip',
  UploadId:
   'qrCiUGI6fspjB7cglWxDXc1vXULbLtkECg9WRdiiDkZsomPjC3BnrV3XfHlSpIbYJKQRpCeHzH8A8nRmK.PRdgSRrdykf74YHY.Sc6wRwRY5oQM4Vsp60Y0x.A.6JdJy' })
Serverless: [AWS s3 200 1.022s 0 retries] uploadPart({ Body:
   <Buffer 2a 81 b7 75 82 b1 63 16 90 11 07 6a e9 d7 37 6b 28 88 b8 ea f0 1f 2d 0d 16 78 70 e5 61 0a fc 07 44 2e 7c 85 45 00 f5 f7 08 4b fc dc 5e 69 47 a2 89 6f ... >,
  ContentLength: 674979,
  PartNumber: 11,
  Bucket:
   'python-lambda6-dev-serverlessdeploymentbucket-1bqpkzk33k7zr',
  Key:
   'serverless/python-lambda6/dev/1583523468652-2020-03-06T19:37:48.652Z/python-lambda6.zip',
  UploadId:
   'qrCiUGI6fspjB7cglWxDXc1vXULbLtkECg9WRdiiDkZsomPjC3BnrV3XfHlSpIbYJKQRpCeHzH8A8nRmK.PRdgSRrdykf74YHY.Sc6wRwRY5oQM4Vsp60Y0x.A.6JdJy' })
Serverless: [AWS s3 200 1.251s 0 retries] uploadPart({ Body:
   <Buffer e8 08 e8 f9 40 d4 63 49 37 06 94 85 fc 46 3d f2 ba 4c 3e 88 db 77 d9 1c dd 4b 1f bd dd 9b 7c fc 77 6e f6 bc fc d6 c7 f9 07 c4 7f f9 fc bc 7d 61 de be ... >,
  ContentLength: 5242880,
  PartNumber: 10,
  Bucket:
   'python-lambda6-dev-serverlessdeploymentbucket-1bqpkzk33k7zr',
  Key:
   'serverless/python-lambda6/dev/1583523468652-2020-03-06T19:37:48.652Z/python-lambda6.zip',
  UploadId:
   'qrCiUGI6fspjB7cglWxDXc1vXULbLtkECg9WRdiiDkZsomPjC3BnrV3XfHlSpIbYJKQRpCeHzH8A8nRmK.PRdgSRrdykf74YHY.Sc6wRwRY5oQM4Vsp60Y0x.A.6JdJy' })
Serverless: [AWS s3 200 3.474s 0 retries] uploadPart({ Body:
   <Buffer d9 b2 40 4f 29 f6 cc 48 72 aa 76 10 96 91 65 62 76 e1 25 ca bf 50 2d d1 cc b8 25 0a 3f c9 4a d2 2b bc 97 85 5f f7 c3 ef 49 0f a4 25 a3 69 37 a3 34 f1 ... >,
  ContentLength: 5242880,
  PartNumber: 8,
  Bucket:
   'python-lambda6-dev-serverlessdeploymentbucket-1bqpkzk33k7zr',
  Key:
   'serverless/python-lambda6/dev/1583523468652-2020-03-06T19:37:48.652Z/python-lambda6.zip',
  UploadId:
   'qrCiUGI6fspjB7cglWxDXc1vXULbLtkECg9WRdiiDkZsomPjC3BnrV3XfHlSpIbYJKQRpCeHzH8A8nRmK.PRdgSRrdykf74YHY.Sc6wRwRY5oQM4Vsp60Y0x.A.6JdJy' })
Serverless: [AWS s3 200 5.209s 0 retries] uploadPart({ Body:
   <Buffer 95 92 f1 e9 4a 7f 23 95 f2 1d 95 76 38 6e a5 f5 ea 76 a9 54 5a cf 52 bb 46 b3 d2 5f d4 b4 28 cd 3d a8 f8 0e 5c d5 3c ea 37 6b 2c 00 8f 12 57 1c 27 87 ... >,
  ContentLength: 5242880,
  PartNumber: 6,
  Bucket:
   'python-lambda6-dev-serverlessdeploymentbucket-1bqpkzk33k7zr',
  Key:
   'serverless/python-lambda6/dev/1583523468652-2020-03-06T19:37:48.652Z/python-lambda6.zip',
  UploadId:
   'qrCiUGI6fspjB7cglWxDXc1vXULbLtkECg9WRdiiDkZsomPjC3BnrV3XfHlSpIbYJKQRpCeHzH8A8nRmK.PRdgSRrdykf74YHY.Sc6wRwRY5oQM4Vsp60Y0x.A.6JdJy' })
Serverless: [AWS s3 200 0.16s 0 retries] completeMultipartUpload({ MultipartUpload:
   { Parts:
      [ { ETag: '"fe8f4a724f152821d50efaddc5da405f"', PartNumber: 1 },
        { ETag: '"c8b59ad4abef4e54f63172de3d24cd44"', PartNumber: 2 },
        { ETag: '"7c9f2dd98598903a8e587bf88fa74a63"', PartNumber: 3 },
        { ETag: '"e851505654424a7f8e756163ab88117d"', PartNumber: 4 },
        { ETag: '"1d79035bfeb2913e7ab51a00b88840f9"', PartNumber: 5 },
        { ETag: '"bd6b292c92df2ed2b29e64b15218bfd7"', PartNumber: 6 },
        { ETag: '"74adb3431c5774e555b854ab64fc4282"', PartNumber: 7 },
        { ETag: '"e94d3b4b0bb989f2b50368cd1720465e"', PartNumber: 8 },
        { ETag: '"e6bc46f097590dd8ba7cfbeb11aafa95"', PartNumber: 9 },
        { ETag: '"b21d9105275a05da5722f142e8835d3a"', PartNumber: 10 },
        { ETag: '"26ed61fa0aed712d9ae114d14d92dbdb"', PartNumber: 11 },
        [length]: 11 ] },
  Bucket:
   'python-lambda6-dev-serverlessdeploymentbucket-1bqpkzk33k7zr',
  Key:
   'serverless/python-lambda6/dev/1583523468652-2020-03-06T19:37:48.652Z/python-lambda6.zip',
  UploadId:
   'qrCiUGI6fspjB7cglWxDXc1vXULbLtkECg9WRdiiDkZsomPjC3BnrV3XfHlSpIbYJKQRpCeHzH8A8nRmK.PRdgSRrdykf74YHY.Sc6wRwRY5oQM4Vsp60Y0x.A.6JdJy' })
Serverless: Validating template...
Serverless: [AWS cloudformation 200 0.408s 0 retries] validateTemplate({ TemplateURL:
   'https://s3.amazonaws.com/python-lambda6-dev-serverlessdeploymentbucket-1bqpkzk33k7zr/serverless/python-lambda6/dev/1583523468652-2020-03-06T19:37:48.652Z/compiled-cloudformation-template.json' })
Serverless: Updating Stack...
Serverless: [AWS cloudformation 200 0.512s 0 retries] updateStack({ StackName: 'python-lambda6-dev',
  Capabilities: [ 'CAPABILITY_IAM', 'CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM', [length]: 2 ],
  Parameters: [ [length]: 0 ],
  TemplateURL:
   'https://s3.amazonaws.com/python-lambda6-dev-serverlessdeploymentbucket-1bqpkzk33k7zr/serverless/python-lambda6/dev/1583523468652-2020-03-06T19:37:48.652Z/compiled-cloudformation-template.json',
  Tags: [ { Key: 'STAGE', Value: 'dev' }, [length]: 1 ] })
Serverless: Checking Stack update progress...
Serverless: [AWS cloudformation 200 0.122s 0 retries] describeStackEvents({ StackName:
   'arn:aws:cloudformation:ca-central-1:944837795657:stack/python-lambda6-dev/f684f390-5fe1-11ea-b064-02dcd16b7172' })
.........Serverless: [AWS cloudformation 200 0.127s 0 retries] describeStackEvents({ StackName:
   'arn:aws:cloudformation:ca-central-1:944837795657:stack/python-lambda6-dev/f684f390-5fe1-11ea-b064-02dcd16b7172' })
...Serverless: [AWS cloudformation 200 0.127s 0 retries] describeStackEvents({ StackName:
   'arn:aws:cloudformation:ca-central-1:944837795657:stack/python-lambda6-dev/f684f390-5fe1-11ea-b064-02dcd16b7172' })
Serverless: [AWS cloudformation 200 0.15s 0 retries] describeStackEvents({ StackName:
   'arn:aws:cloudformation:ca-central-1:944837795657:stack/python-lambda6-dev/f684f390-5fe1-11ea-b064-02dcd16b7172' })
.Serverless: [AWS cloudformation 200 0.125s 0 retries] describeStackEvents({ StackName:
   'arn:aws:cloudformation:ca-central-1:944837795657:stack/python-lambda6-dev/f684f390-5fe1-11ea-b064-02dcd16b7172' })
...Serverless: [AWS cloudformation 200 0.148s 0 retries] describeStackEvents({ StackName:
   'arn:aws:cloudformation:ca-central-1:944837795657:stack/python-lambda6-dev/f684f390-5fe1-11ea-b064-02dcd16b7172' })
..............Serverless: [AWS cloudformation 200 0.155s 0 retries] describeStackEvents({ StackName:
   'arn:aws:cloudformation:ca-central-1:944837795657:stack/python-lambda6-dev/f684f390-5fe1-11ea-b064-02dcd16b7172' })
Serverless: [AWS cloudformation 200 0.145s 0 retries] describeStackEvents({ StackName:
   'arn:aws:cloudformation:ca-central-1:944837795657:stack/python-lambda6-dev/f684f390-5fe1-11ea-b064-02dcd16b7172' })
...
Serverless: Stack update finished...
Serverless: Invoke aws:info
Serverless: [AWS cloudformation 200 0.105s 0 retries] describeStacks({ StackName: 'python-lambda6-dev' })
Serverless: [AWS cloudformation 200 0.116s 0 retries] listStackResources({ StackName: 'python-lambda6-dev' })
Service Information
service: python-lambda6
stage: dev
region: ca-central-1
stack: python-lambda6-dev
resources: 12
api keys:
  None
endpoints:
  ANY - https://z77mz2m3w6.execute-api.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev
  ANY - https://z77mz2m3w6.execute-api.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev/{proxy+}
functions:
  numpy: python-lambda6-dev-numpy
layers:
  None
Serverless: Invoke aws:deploy:finalize
Serverless: [AWS s3 200 0.139s 0 retries] listObjectsV2({ Bucket:
   'python-lambda6-dev-serverlessdeploymentbucket-1bqpkzk33k7zr',
  Prefix: 'serverless/python-lambda6/dev' })
Serverless: Run the "serverless" command to setup monitoring, troubleshooting and testing.
```

### Output of invoke

```
$ SLS_DEBUG=* serverless invoke -f numpy
Serverless: Load command interactiveCli
Serverless: Load command config
Serverless: Load command config:credentials
Serverless: Load command create
Serverless: Load command install
Serverless: Load command package
Serverless: Load command deploy
Serverless: Load command deploy:function
Serverless: Load command deploy:list
Serverless: Load command deploy:list:functions
Serverless: Load command invoke
Serverless: Load command invoke:local
Serverless: Load command info
Serverless: Load command logs
Serverless: Load command metrics
Serverless: Load command print
Serverless: Load command remove
Serverless: Load command rollback
Serverless: Load command rollback:function
Serverless: Load command slstats
Serverless: Load command plugin
Serverless: Load command plugin
Serverless: Load command plugin:install
Serverless: Load command plugin
Serverless: Load command plugin:uninstall
Serverless: Load command plugin
Serverless: Load command plugin:list
Serverless: Load command plugin
Serverless: Load command plugin:search
Serverless: Load command config
Serverless: Load command config:credentials
Serverless: Load command rollback
Serverless: Load command rollback:function
Serverless: Load command upgrade
Serverless: Load command uninstall
Serverless: Load command requirements
Serverless: Load command requirements:clean
Serverless: Load command requirements:install
Serverless: Load command requirements:cleanCache
Serverless: Load command login
Serverless: Load command logout
Serverless: Load command generate-event
Serverless: Load command test
Serverless: Load command dashboard
Serverless: Load command output
Serverless: Load command output:get
Serverless: Load command output:list
Serverless: Load command param
Serverless: Load command param:get
Serverless: Load command param:list
Serverless: Invoke invoke
```

Thanks,
Kala

Comment: Would you please add a few additional details so that we could help?
Please include the output of `SLS_DEBUG=* serverless invoke -f function_name`

Comment: @AaronStuyvenberg, please find below the output of the above command in the question. along with the code I used. It stalls at Invoke invoke

Comment: Thanks for adding your handler code! you're not returning anything from your handler at all.

Can you please add:
```
    body = {
        "message": "Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!",
        "input": event
    }


    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps(body)
    }

    return response
```

Comment: @AaronStuyvenberg, thanks for your reply. But it still stalls on invoking it using the command. If its invoked through the browser it works good.

Comment: import numpy as np
import json

def main(event, context):
    a = np.arange(15).reshape(3, 5);
    print("Your numpy array:")
    print(a)

    body = {
        "message": "Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!",
        "input": event
    }

    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps(body)
    }

    return response


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main('', '')

Comment: service: python-lambda4

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  stage: dev
  region: ca-central-1

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux

functions:
  numpy:
    handler: handler.main
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: 'ANY {proxy+}'

Comment: These are my updated files

Comment: Hey Kalatheeswaran - I was able to get your question re-opened. Could you please edit your post with the new files so I can help you further?

And the output of `sls deploy` too. Thanks!!

Comment: @AaronStuyvenberg, I have updated the requested files with o/p of sls deploy. Thanks for reopening the question.

Comment: @AaronStuyvenberg, can you help me with this please?